# Built in binary search for an integer value without forming the array?

Tags: c++, stl, binary-search

I'm searching for a solution `k` such that's an integer value from `1` to `n` such that `k` is the smallest value such that `k * (k + 1) >= 2 * n`.

I know I can do

```
int n{100};
std::vector<int> v(n);
std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 1);
auto it = lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 2 * n, [n](const auto &lhs, const auto &rhs)
{
    // return lhs < rhs;
    return (lhs * (lhs + 1) < rhs);
});
auto answer = *it;
```

I don't want to have to form `v`, which I believe means there's no way I can use `std::lower_bound`. I currently have my own custom binary search function to solve this, but I was wondering if there's already an STL function that does exactly this, without forming an array?

Comment: You could write a custom iterator that doesn't go to an array, but frankly reimplementing the algo is probably easier.

Comment: Isn't the answer just `k = sqrt(2 * n)`?

Comment: @NathanOliver I had `k = ceil([-1 +/- sqrt(1 + 8n)] / 2)`. Let me see if that's equivalent to what you have. (However, I was specifically trying to solve this with binary search)

Comment: @NathanOliver No, I tried using a floor and ceiling on `sqrt(2 * n)`, and it overestimates by 1 on some cases of `n` and underestimates by 1 for some cases of `n`.

Comment: Could you give me an example where it fails?

Comment: @NathanOliver For `n = 11`, floor(sqrt(2*n)) gives ` k = 4`, but `4 * (4 + 1) / 2 < 22`. For `n = 13`, ceil(sqrt(2*n)) gives ` k = 6`, but `k = 5` is the answer.

Comment: Cool, thanks.  If you want to do this as a binary search, just get rid of the array and use a regular loop instead.  It's cool to be able to the standard algorithms but not all problems need them to be used to solve them.

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely overkill, but you can define an iterator type that mimics an array of consecutive integers, and call `lower_bound` on a pair of those iterators

```
struct IotaIter {
    typedef const int       value_type;
    typedef std::ptrdiff_t  difference_type;
    typedef const int *     pointer;
    typedef const int &     reference;
    typedef std::random_access_iterator_tag  iterator_category;

    int value;
    IotaIter(int v) : value(v) {}
    IotaIter(const IotaIter &) = default;
    IotaIter& operator = (const IotaIter &) = default;
    
    const int & operator* () const noexcept { return value; }
    
    IotaIter& operator+= (int offset) noexcept { value +=   offset;  return *this; }
    IotaIter& operator-= (int offset) noexcept { value += (-offset); return *this; }

    IotaIter operator++() noexcept
    { ++value; return *this;}
    IotaIter operator++(int) noexcept
    { IotaIter tmp(*this); ++(*this); return tmp;}

    IotaIter operator--() noexcept
    { --value; return *this;}
    IotaIter operator--(int) noexcept
    { IotaIter tmp(*this); --(*this); return tmp;}
};

bool
operator==(const IotaIter &rhs, const IotaIter &lhs) _NOEXCEPT
{ return rhs.value == lhs.value; }

bool
operator!=(const IotaIter &rhs, const IotaIter &lhs) _NOEXCEPT
{ return rhs.value != lhs.value; }

bool
operator< (const IotaIter &rhs, const IotaIter &lhs) _NOEXCEPT
{ return rhs.value <  lhs.value; }

bool
operator<=(const IotaIter &rhs, const IotaIter &lhs) _NOEXCEPT
{ return rhs.value <= lhs.value; }

bool
operator>(const IotaIter &rhs, const IotaIter &lhs) _NOEXCEPT
{ return rhs.value >  lhs.value; }

bool
operator>=(const IotaIter &rhs, const IotaIter &lhs) _NOEXCEPT
{ return rhs.value >= lhs.value; }

IotaIter operator+ (const IotaIter &rhs, int offset)
{ return IotaIter (rhs.value + offset); }

IotaIter::difference_type operator- (const IotaIter &rhs, const IotaIter &lhs)
{ return rhs.value - lhs.value; }


int main () {
    const int n = 100;
    IotaIter it = std::lower_bound(IotaIter(0), IotaIter(n),
                        2 * n,
                        [n](const auto &lhs, const auto &rhs)
                        {
                            // return lhs < rhs;
                            return (lhs * (lhs + 1) < rhs);
                        });

    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Apparently you don't need to capture `n`.

Comment: You are correct. I just grabbed that from the OP's code. It is not necessary there, either.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can make a custom iterator:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iterator>

template <class T>
struct IntegralIterator final {
  T t;
  using value_type = const int;
  using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
  using pointer = const int*;
  using reference = const int&;
  using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
  using size_type = std::size_t;

  [[nodiscard]] constexpr T operator[](size_type const i) const noexcept {
    return t + i;
  }

  [[nodiscard]] constexpr auto operator==(
      IntegralIterator const& other) const noexcept {
    return t == other.t;
  }

  [[nodiscard]] constexpr auto operator!=(
      IntegralIterator const& other) const noexcept {
    return !(t == other.t);
  }
  [[nodiscard]] constexpr auto operator-(
      IntegralIterator const& rhs) const noexcept {
    return t - rhs.t;
  }

  [[maybe_unused]] constexpr auto operator*() const noexcept { return t; }

  [[maybe_unused]] constexpr auto& operator+=(size_type const dist) noexcept {
    t += static_cast<int>(dist);
    return *this;
  }
  [[nodiscard]] constexpr auto operator+(size_type const dist) noexcept {
    auto copy = *this;
    (*this) += dist;
    return copy;
  }
  [[maybe_unused]] constexpr auto& operator-=(size_type const dist) noexcept {
    t -= static_cast<int>(dist);
    return *this;
  }
  [[nodiscard]] constexpr auto operator-(size_type const dist) noexcept {
    auto copy = *this;
    (*this) -= dist;
    return copy;
  }
  [[maybe_unused]] constexpr auto& operator++() noexcept {
    ++t;
    return *this;
  }
  [[maybe_unused]] constexpr auto& operator--() noexcept {
    --t;
    return *this;
  }
  [[nodiscard]] constexpr auto operator++(int) noexcept {
    auto copy = *this;
    ++(*this);
    return copy;
  }
  [[nodiscard]] constexpr auto operator--(int) noexcept {
    auto copy = *this;
    --(*this);
    return copy;
  }
};

int alg(int const n) {
  IntegralIterator<int> beg{0}, end{n + 1};
  return *std::lower_bound(
      beg, end, 2 * n,
      [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) { return (lhs * (lhs + 1) < rhs); });
}

int main() {
  std::printf("%d\n", alg(100));
}
```

Comment: Ha! You were 43 seconds faster than I was!

Comment: @MarshallClow it worked on VS, something seems wrong on clang+gcc. So, you still have time until I figure out what's up :D https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/7hx7b91EY

Comment: Strictly speaking neither your iterator nor mine is conforming, because it doesn't have a `operator[]`. But whatever.

Comment: @MarshallClow Well, until recently I didn't even know iterators define that operator. And always used `*(it + n)`.  Anyways, I was missing some typedefs. I wish there was some way to explicitly ask the compiler to make sure you've implemented the interface correctly.